# No discord bot status

Tags: discord, bots

How can I make a discord bot have no status like not be in online, idle, invisible, do not disturb just no status some bots have that and I'm curious how its done my bots also in discord.js

I keep trying multiple times but it doesn't work I also can't find any way in the guides to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

These bots run through the application webhook and do not connect through the main Discord gateway. You must therefore respond to slash commands or other interactions exclusively through the application webhook - note that this excludes the events from being sent to the gateway. If your bot responds to events such as messages, reactions, or members joining, you have to set your status to offline.

See the following tutorial from the Discord API docs: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/blob/main/docs/tutorials/Hosting_on_Cloudflare_Workers.md